# IBM Watson ToneAnalyzerV3 WatsonException: Error: Invalid JSON input, Code: 400

Tags: python, json, ibm-watson, watson, tone-analyzer

The following set of code work when I have short text but when I give it a longer text of this form: https://pastebin.com/PLinyN65

```
import os
import json
from watson_developer_cloud import ToneAnalyzerV3 
from glob import glob

with open(credentials.txt) as cred:
    data = cred.readlines()
    UserName = data[0]
    PassWord = data[1]

tone_analyzer = ToneAnalyzerV3(
                username=UserName,
                password=PassWord,
                version='2016-05-19')

pth = '../input/*.txt'
txtFiles = glob(pth)
for file in txtFiles:
    baseName = os.path.basename(file) 
    name = baseName.split('.')

with open(file) as f:
    txt = f.read()

    with open('../output/{}.json'.format(name[0]), 'w') as outFile:
        json.dump(tone_analyzer.tone(text=txt, sentences='false'), outFile, separators=(',', ': '), indent=2)
```

I get the error:

```
WatsonException                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-d948e97e307e> in <module>()
      8 
      9         with open('../output/{}.json'.format(name[0]), 'w') as outFile:
---> 10             json.dump(tone_analyzer.tone(text=txt, sentences='false'), outFile, separators=(',', ': '), indent=2)
     11 
     12     print('{}\n'.format(name[0]))

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/watson_developer_cloud/tone_analyzer_v3.pyc in tone(self, text, tones, sentences)
     51         data = {'text': text}
     52         return self.request(method='POST', url='/v3/tone', params=params,
---> 53                             json=data, accept_json=True)

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/watson_developer_cloud/watson_developer_cloud_service.pyc in request(self, method, url, accept_json, headers, params, json, data, files, **kwargs)
    318             else:
    319                 error_message = self._get_error_message(response)
--> 320             raise WatsonException(error_message)

WatsonException: Error: Invalid JSON input, Code: 400
```

When I try to manually input the text on this weblink: https://tone-analyzer-demo.mybluemix.net/

I get the error: `request entity too large`

Please advice how I can get the required tone analysis scores in json format from ToneAnalyzerV3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the Tone Analyzer API Explorer, you can see there is a limit on the amount of text each request can handle:

> The Tone Analyzer service supports up to 128 KB of text, or about 1000
>   sentences. Sentences with less than three words cannot be analyzed.

[Tone Analyzer API Explorer](https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/apis/tone-analyzer-v3#!/tone/tone)

The text you provided is 165,743 bytes (168 KB), which is larger than what the service supports. I attempted to input the text provided above in the API Explorer and received the same error as you have above:

```
{
  "code": 400,
  "sub_code": "C00013",
  "error": "Invalid JSON input"
}
```

As a solution you will need to use a text input that is below the maximum of 128 KB of text.